# Bash script. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, ssh, chmod

What am I doing wrong? Trying to execute `chmod o-w` for multiple paths after ssh to one server.
File 1.txt contains two columns; one with same server called SERVER_hostname and second with different paths. I want script to ssh to that specific server hostname, and then make myself root(either toor, sudo eksh) and then run the command 'chmod o-w ' to those different paths from second column.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -a server < 1.txt  
echo "${server[0]}"  
echo "ssh -oBatchMode=yes -q "$(echo "${server[0]}")"  '"$(cat 1.txt | awk '{print " sudo eksh ; \ chmod o-w  " $NF";"}')"'" | sh
```

---

```
./254.sh  
SERVER_hostname
awk: warning: escape sequence `\ ' treated as plain ` '  
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/etc/nginx-controller/agent.configurator.conf.default’: Operation not permitted  
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/etc/nginx-controller/agent.controller.conf.default’: Operation not permitted    
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/etc/nginx-controller/copyright’: Operation not permitted  
chmod: missing operand after ‘o-w’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

---

1.txt

```
SERVER_hostname /etc/nginx-controller/agent.configurator.conf.default  
SERVER_hostname /etc/nginx-controller/agent.controller.conf.default  
SERVER_hostname /etc/nginx-controller/copyright
```

Comment: Hi Bogdan and welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the goal you want to achieve with the command you have assembled? Could you [edit] your question to fill in the specifics. This will allows us to help you in a more productive way. We could just fix the code not to have an error, but I doubt it will run in a way you would like it to run.

Comment: Thank you. The script goal is to execute chmod o-w for multiple paths after ssh to one server. File 1.txt contains two columns; one with same server called SERVER_hostname and second with different paths. I want script to ssh to that specific server hostname, and then make myself root(either toor, sudo eksh) and then run the command 'chmod o-w ' to those different paths from second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways of achieving this. But all have some tricks up their sleeve due to the usage of `ssh`. When using ssh in loops or complex constructs, you always have to be aware that `ssh` will slurp your `/dev/stdin`

The quickest way to implement would be to do multiple calls to ssh using a while-loop to read the file (See [BashFAQ#001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)). However, we force `ssh` to use `/dev/null` as input stream. This way we avoid that the while loop is broken:

```
while read -r host file; do
  [ "$host" ] || continue
  [ "$file" ] || continue
  </dev/null ssh -oBatchMode=yes -q "${host}" -- sudo eksh -c "chmod o-w -- ${file}"
done < file.txt
```

The above method will perform multiple calls to ssh and might not be the most efficient way of doing things. You could build up the command using an array to contain the command arguments (See [BashFAQ#050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). In the case of the OP, this would be the different filenames:

```
file_list=()
while read -r h f; do [ "$f" ] && file_list+=( "${f}" ); [ "$h" ] && host="$h"; done < file.txt
ssh -oBatchMode=yes -q "${host}" -- sudo eksh -c "chmod o-w -- ${file_list[@]}"
```

But again, there is an issue here if your argument list is too long. So the trick is now to use `xargs` directly over ssh. You could do something like this:

```
file_list=()
while read -r h f; do [ "$f" ] && file_list+=( "${f}" ); [ "$h" ] && host="$h"; done < file.txt
printf "%s\n" "${file_list[@]}" | ssh "$host" "cat - | sudo eksh -c 'xargs chmod o-w --'"
```

**Note:** for some reason the command `ssh "$host" sudo eksh -c 'xargs chmod o-w --'` does not work. That is why we introduce the `cat -`

Comment: this last below worked perfectly. Thank you so much for patience and interest!
file_list=()
while read -r h f; do [ "$f" ] && file_list+=( "${f}" ); [ "$h" ] && host="$h"; done < 254.txt
printf "%s\n" "${file_list[@]}" | ssh -oBatchMode=yes -q "$host" "cat - | sudo /usr/localcw/bin/eksh -c 'xargs chmod o-w --'" 

should I remove all comments above and leave this or how should I proceed to have this as the final answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Bogdan I'm glad to see it all worked out in the end. I think it is best if we remove all comments from here as this has no additional value to the question and answer. You can leave the final answer in the comment.

Comment: Accepted the answer though for casting a vote I need 15 reputations it says and I can’t yet. Hopefully when I will get those reputations will be able to come back and do it.

Comment: No worries, just happy it all worked out in the end!